Meta Symbol broken on Mobile
In the mobile SE app, Crypto.SE has the new symbol, but Meta.Crypto.SE retained its old one, see the below screenshot.
If using the browser, Meta has a grayed version of our new symbol.



shouldiblamecaching.com? It does appear now for me.

@ArtjomB., thank you. Clearing the cache indeed resolved the issue.

This issue was caused by caching of the old symbol, as was noted in the comments.
If you are experiencing the same issue, clear the cache of the app (system's settings) and restart the app. This will load the new (fancy) symbol from the server.
